# Windows Service or Console App?

Tags: c#

Am quite running out of ideas,

Here is what am trying to do ,
i have two table

TableA and Table B.

TableA has four fields (Cust.No, Cust.Name, Description,FlagCust)

Table B has three fields (cust.No, City,country)

my requirement is check the "**FlagCust**"(its a boolean value) column every 20 mints and if its true then grab the details of the customer from TableA and Table B.

But the problem am facing here is i have to communicate the **DB** thru **WCF** service and this will run every 20 mins periodically.

some of them suggest write a console app and run it in a schedule task,others suggest write windows service to do the job.

Here little bit more after getting those records

once i get the data for example **customer name** and **Description**,in the table A tells about the customer data file and where its located the other upload and download process already i have will go and download the customer file and upload to some other place based on the description details.

And am not sure how to handle the multiple records in this scenario,when its retrieved more than one record for download and upload process.

Comment: there one important info missing: what do you have to do with the data you "grab"ed?

Comment: that's a good question,once i get the data for example customer name,in the table A and description tells about the file where the customer details i will go and download the customer file and upload to some other place.

Comment: in a simple word the TableA table tells where and what file i have to download and upload to where

Comment: the big problem i have right now is ,based on the customer name and description details in Table A, i have to download those files from different location and upload to somewhere.Those details i have it in my description.how can i handle those part,if my table retruns 10 records then how it works ?

Comment: You can basically do the same thing using a scheduled task and a Windows Service. So the main question to ask yourself is not really 'what do I want to do?' but 'How do I want to do?' Both run in background but in a different way: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2005/10/24/428303.aspx

Comment: @Guillaume, both looks very confusing to me based on my scenario.I don't know how the heck gonna achieve this task,looks very complicated to me bcoz of very less knowledge

Comment: @Usher Then I think it's more a question of how to design your program. I would suggest your to write your program in a library. Once it's done, you can decide to ship it within a Console application or a Windows Service. Any of them being just a shell that loads and call your library. If for some reason you need to change later how your program is used, it will be easy to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no right answer here. Both solutions will work.

A service will be a little more complicated to develop, but it will give you more flexibility - it's easier not to run two checks at once, if one of them for example takes 20 minutes for some reason, and you have better reporting if it crashes (as well as the ability to restart it automatically).

I'd go with a service if you need it to be more reliable, but going with a scheduled task can also work.

Comment: the big problem i have right now is ,based on the customer name and description details in Table A, i have to download those files from different location and upload to somewhere.Those details i have it in my description.how can i handle those part,if my table retruns 10 records then how it works ?

Comment: Appreciate if you provide some examples or where i can i find one to start with. Thanks again for your help

Comment: You should start searching for downloading and uploading files (HttpRequest is probably your friend here). Anyway, if you have a lot of network operations involved, you should *definitely* go for a service.

Answer (score 1):

Also consider [Quartz.NET - Enterprise Job Scheduler for .NET Platform](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/index.html).

I suggest starting with the tutorial: http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 1):

For stuff like this that only needs to operate periodically I would probably advocate using the Windows scheduler. That's what it's for.

If you write a service then it's yet another process sat open doing nothing. I can't be the only one who gets annoyed at all the services and processes sat on my machine who's only job is to check for software updates periodically. The scheduler is a service designed to replace all these separate services.

The only time I write a genuine service is when it must be responsive all the time, even if it's only used infrequently (eg servicing comms requests).